# Unable to reproduce Web.dev console errors

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, developer-tools, lighthouse

Web.dev shows that there are console errors from third party tracking software (LuckyOrange):

> WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment:
>   net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Tried to reproduce same error with *Lighthouse* in *Chrome DevTools*, also with *Lighthouse CLI*, *Headless Chrome*. Was unable to do that. There are no errors in browser console too.

Maybe somebody have experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with this. I have always ignored these warnings as they are inconsistent. I THINK they are caused by my CDN blocking the automated requests, resulting in console errors. For me it happens every now and then and only after repeated querying.

Note that I have no proof for this theory.

Comment: Have contacted LuckyOrange support. They said that is expected situation because Lighthouse is not loading the site in the same way that it would load in a user's browser so we can end up with weird errors like this. Looks like they need to fix that from their side.